# XML coordinates to variable

Tags: javascript, xml

I would like to get div position from xml
xml look like this:

```
<coord>140X 120Y</coord>
```

i have stored both of them in one variable

```
Coord=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("coord")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

i would like to separate X in one variable and Y in another, so i could set position for my div
if you have link to some tutorial, which could help me, I would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got the element data in a string:

```
String XmlCord = "140X 120Y";

String[] Numbers = XmlCord.Split(new char[] {'X', ' ', 'Y'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int X, Y;

if (int.TryParse(Numbers[0], out X) == false)
{
    // handle error
}
if (int.TryParse(Numbers[1], out Y) == false)
{
    // handle error
}
```

I miss sscanf from C++.

You might be better off storing the data as attributes, something like:

```
<coord X="140" Y="120" ></coord>
```

Comment: This is not javascript. At all.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize it was client side.  What a pity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JavaScript's [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions), [matching groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches) in particular.  For example:

```
var coord = "140X 120Y"
  , regex = /^(\d+)X\s+(\d+)Y$/
  , m = coord.match(regex), x, y;
if (m) {
  x = Number(m[1]); // => 140
  y = Number(m[2]); // => 120
}
```